# React Native Negative shadowOffset to create top shadow

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a bottom navigation bar like YouTube or Instagram have but I am running into issue creating the shadow effect:

This is my current code;

```
  shadowColor: '#000000',
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  },
  shadowRadius: 50,
  shadowOpacity: 1.0,
  elevation: 1
```

This produces a shadow that is only visible on the bottom of the navigation bar but not on the top. Is there a way to place a negative shadowOffset so that the shadow is also visible on the top?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I have a similar use case.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add small marginTop to your container, than add styles:

```
{
  shadowRadius: 2,
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: -3,
  },
  shadowColor: '#000000',
  elevation: 4,
}
```

Comment: I needed to add the `shadowOpacity` prop as well as the above, with the exception of marginTop. (e.g. `shadowOpacity: 1.0,`)

Comment: not working at all

Answer (score 0):

shadowOffset and shadowRadius only work in ios. Android not working.